# Make file readonly in finder but writable in c program

Tags: c, linux, permissions

I am making a c version of pacman and am keeping my highscores in a separate .txt file called highscores.txt.  In the program, after the completion of a game, it checks to see if the highscores file should be updated and writes over it if it should.  The high scores view within the program reads the scores and names from the file.  The issue is that it is very easy for someone to simply edit the .txt file and say they got any score they wanted.  Is there a way to make it so that the file can only be written on by the program? This is in a Linux Red Hat environment.

Comment: There is no completely foolproof way to do this, but one possibility would be a fake userid with no password (note: not the same thing as an empty password), that your program is setuid to, and your scores file only has write permission for that uid, and read permission for others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say just encript the file, then rename it something obscure.
An easy way will be to gzip it, and name as a file called "data" or whatever, so people couldn't guess it's gzip. 
This method is easy to break once you know gzip is used, so a more secure way is to encript it using an encription key internal in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably encryption. A good, quick study on [Encoding vs. Encrypting vs Hashing](http://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding_encryption_hashing/)

You could also look at other ways of storing the data. For example, something like HSQLDB or SQLLite, where you can create databases that have usernames and passwords available.